# How to scroll in android using java appium client?

Tags: java, android, mobile, automation, appium

I am trying to automate a native android app using Appium. I am using the java client for the same. Below are the dependencies that I have included. Since I am using version 7 of the java client, there's no support for scroll and swipe method. SO alternatively how do I scroll to a particular element?? I have come across some code snippets using TouchAction class, but I just want to know if there's any alternative solution apart from the TouchAction class??
Maven dependency -

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.testng</groupId>
<artifactId>testng</artifactId>
<version>6.8</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>io.appium</groupId>
<artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
<version>7.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **findElementByAndroidUIAutomator** with different conditions like text,description:

```
((AndroidDriver<?>) appiumDriver).findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\""+ text + "\").instance(0))");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public MobileElement scrollElementByTextUsingDescription(String scrollableListContDesc, String uiClassSelector, String text) {
        return driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator(
           "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().description(\"" + scrollableList + "\"))" +
           ".getChildByText(new UiSelector().className(\"" + uiClassSelector + "\"), \"" + text + "\")"));
    }
```

> **scrollableListContDesc** is automationId/cont-Description of scrollable list
>
> **uiClassSelector** is the class name of scrollable list e.g android.view.View
>
> **text** is the text of the element upto where you want to scroll.

If you don't have **cont-description** in scrollable list, you can use following method:

```
public MobileElement scrollElementByTextUsingId(String scrollableListId, String uiClassSelector, String text) {
            return driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator(
               "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceId(\"" + scrollableListId + "\"))" +
               ".getChildByText(new UiSelector().className(\"" + uiClassSelector + "\"), \"" + text + "\")"));
        }
```

> **scrollableListId** is id/resourceId of scrollable list

Answer (score -1):

UIScrollable/UISelector is one alternative to TouchActions that you can use to scroll/swipe. Example:

```
MobileElement element = driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator(
            "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceId(\"com.android.vending:id/data_view\")).scrollIntoView("
            + "new UiSelector().textContains(\"HelloWorld\").instance(2))"));
```

[This](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/appium-scroll-examples/) blog post covers a variety of solutions to swipe/scroll well.